Codeblocks retorna valor negativo em vez de 0
Como o código funciona:
pra chegar na seção de código problemática, o usuário deve estar num modo de operação que lê um arquivo de texto específico, direcionado pelo ponteiro "file". Então, o arquivo é lido pela função "fgetc" e armazena numa string chamada "buffer" que para de ser lida quando encontra um caractere definido por mim como o caractere que finaliza a leitura, o "!". A partir disso, a string "buffer" passa por 3 ciclos "for" para armazenar os conteudos das linhas 1, 2 e 3 nas strings "pastaa" (o numero da pasta que os valores estão armazenados) "proprietarioo" (o nome do proprietario do imovel) e "inquilinoo" (o nome do inquilino do imovel). Obs.: as variaveis "j", "k" e "h" são definidas como 0 inicialmente, elas fazem o papel de armazenar algo que está no meio da string "buffer" na posição inicialmente 0 da string onde se está armazenando os caracteres.
Mas o erro está justamente quando eu acrescento um ciclo (for, while ou do while) junto com a variavel "contadorPastas", o programa roda por 3 ciclos e depois para de rodar e retorna um valor inteiro negativo e grande. Podem me ajudar?
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 0;

char buffer[101];
char pastaa[1];
char proprietarioo[50];
char inquilinoo[50];
int aa = 0;
int contadorPastas = 0;

struct modelo {

int a2;
char proprietario[20];
char inquilino[20];

};

int main (void){

int i = 0;
int modo;

printf("Digite o modo de utilizacao:");
scanf("%i", &modo);

if(modo == 0){

printf("Digite o numero de pastas: ");
scanf("%i", &a);

}
if(modo == 1){
    printf("Digite o numero de pastas a serem adicionadas:");
    scanf("%i", &a);
}

struct modelo pasta[a];

struct modelo setar(struct modelo x[a], int y, int z);

setar(pasta, a, modo);

for(; i<a; i++ ){
printf("A pasta %i tem proprietario %s e inquilino %s\n", pasta[i].a2, pasta[i].proprietario, pasta[i].inquilino);

}
return 0;
}

struct modelo setar (struct modelo x[a], int y2, int z2){

FILE *file;

if(z2 == 0){
   file = fopen("C:\\Users\\VINICIUS\\Desktop\\teste.txt", "w");
};
if(z2 == 1){
    file = fopen("C:\\Users\\VINICIUS\\Desktop\\teste.txt", "a");
};
if(z2 == 2){
    int linha = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int q = 0;
    file = fopen("C:\\Users\\VINICIUS\\Desktop\\teste.txt", "r");

    do{
    while((buffer[aa] = fgetc(file)) != '!'){

        aa++;
    };
    aa++;


        for(; linha == 0 && buffer[j]!= '\n'; j++){
            pastaa[j] = buffer[j];

        };
        if(linha == 0 && buffer[j] == '\n'){
           linha = 1;
           j=j+1;
        };
        for(; linha == 1 && buffer[j+k] != '\n'; k++){
            proprietarioo[k] = buffer[j + k];
            
        };
        if (linha == 1 && buffer[j+k] == '\n'){
            linha = 2;
            q = j+k;
        };

        for(; linha == 2 && buffer[q+h]!= '!'; h++){
            inquilinoo[h-1] = buffer[q+h];
        };


    printf("%s, %s, %s", pastaa, proprietarioo, inquilinoo);
    contadorPastas++;

    } while (contadorPastas< 100);
};

if(z2 == 0 || z2 == 1){
for(int i = 0; i< y2; i++){
        printf("\nDigite o numero da pasta: ");
        scanf("%i", &x[i].a2);
        fprintf(file, "%i\n", x[i].a2);
        printf("\nDigite o nome do proprietario: ");
        scanf("%s", &x[i].proprietario);
        fprintf(file, "%s\n", x[i].proprietario);
        printf("\nDigite o nome do inquilino: ");
        scanf("%s", &x[i].inquilino);
        fprintf(file, "%s!\n", x[i].inquilino);
};};

fclose(file);
};



Uma pergunta similar já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
